# User account no longer exists, unable to login to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mount, permissions, login, sudo

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on external hard drive. Earlier, I was able to login to my account without any problem. Now, suddenly, I am unable to do so. The only account available is "Guest". With this account, I tried several suggestions/solutions available on the Internet, however, sudo itself is not permitted:

I get the following error message for:

```
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
```

Also, operations such as `ls` to check if my account exists throws up message:

```
ls: cannot open directory /home: Permission denied
```

There is no root access available also. I would like help to log-in back to my account and get my data back.

Comment: What is an "a/c"? Can you see if your userid is in the `/etc/passwd` file? What did you do between "Earlier" and "Now, suddenly"? Have you tried to login with Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Comment: @waltinator I believe, OP means "account". ;)

Comment: @waltinator +1 for *What did you do between "Earlier" and "Now, suddenly"?*

Comment: Firstly: Ubuntu 12.10 has gone end of life a while back and so did the  support for it on AskUbuntu Secondly: this will be a good moment to upgrade to 14.04 or 15.04. From the looks of it you probably issued a chmod or chown over a directory you should not have messing up permissions on files Ubuntu relies on. You need a LIVE session to change those permissions back but you would also need us to tell what you did for us to be able to help.I would advice to re-install (and backup your data 1st from a "live" session).

Comment: I did not use the disk for quiet some time and logging in to after some time. Live session for help would be good

Answer (score 0):

The system, for whatever reason, is borked.

No matter, you only want to get your data back.

There's not enough information given on what happened to diagnose what went wrong, and it could be many things.

You said it's an external drive.

Startup your main system, on your internal drive, or a live usb stick or live cd, and copy the data from your external drive to somewhere else safe, a network location or perhaps a pen drive.

The file system will likely be ext3, which you can mount with any linux.

All your own data will be in folder /home/your-user-name

Don't for get to copy the files and directories beginning with . in your home folder, which might have things you want to keep like your firefox profiles.

Once you have your data safe, you can perhaps install a clean system on the external drive to get a (newer) version of ubuntu back, then copy back your data.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were a 30k linux admin. My answer was pitched at entry level, and likely isn't any use to you.

Comment: I did not use the disk for quite some time, I connected it back couple of days back and then I figured I cannot log in. The user  id and passwd is right. I did exactly as you said - created another USB stick and booted the system, connected this external drive. I see the data is intact. However, I do not have write access my folder /home/mala. If there is a way to recover without re-installing, I would definitely like to try it out.